# I thought specific activity was a property of the radionuclide?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation, radioactivity, gamma-rays, elements

How can specific activity of Mo-99 be higher for Mo-99 produced from fission than Mo-99 produced from neutron capture? I thought specific activity would be a property of Mo-99 so it will always be the same? Can someone explain what I am understanding wrong please. Thanks.

Btw here's the website that says you can have higer specific activity Mo-99:

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK396163/#sec_2-5-4

Answer (score 1):

As noted, there are two main paths (and several minor ones) for production of $^{99}$Mo, the parent of the heavily used medical radioisotope $^{99m}$Tc. The $^{99}$Mo isotope has a half-life of 2.75 days, and the $^{99m}$Tc has a half-life of only 6 hours.

One production path takes stable $^{98}$Mo and irradiates it with thermal neutrons to drive the $^{98}$Mo(n,$\gamma$)$^{99}$Mo reaction. Going to [ENDF - Evaluated Nuclear Data Files](https://www.nndc.bnl.gov/exfor/endf00.jsp) this has a cross section that looks like:

[image]

Here the blue line is the total cross section for neutron scattering off of $^{98}$Mo, and the green line is the path to $^{99}$Mo. For low energy (i.e. thermal) neutrons such as found in a normal reactor, the cross section isn't horrible (slightly under 10 barns), so you will get production of $^{99}$Mo.
There are then three issues to think about:

1. $^{98}$Mo, while the most abundant Mo isotope, still is only present at the 25% level in naturally occurring Mo. To get higher proportions of $^{98}$Mo you need to do isotope separation, a costly process.
2. When done irradiating, you have a bit of $^{99}$Mo in a lot of $^{98}$Mo (if isotope separated), or even worse in amongst all the other Mo isotopes. Ultimately the patient gets only a bit of $^{99}$Mo decaying to the $^{99m}$Tc useful stuff.
3. The $^{99}$Mo can also undergo neutron reactions during the irradiations to make it in the first place. This may result in formation of $^{100}$Mo, a much more stable (half-life of $10^{18}$years) isotope, wasting the $^{99}$Mo you were trying to make.

The second path is through fission of $^{235}$U and then picking through all the fission products to get the Mo. Seems kind of crazy, right? Well, as it turns out, the [Fission Product Data](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0090375210001018) nicely shows it might not be so crazy. Percentage yield vs mass number looks like:

[image: Fission yield vs mass]

Note that mass 99 is quite nicely near the top of the left (lower mass) hump. However, a mass of 99 does not mean it has to be $^{99}$Mo. Because $^{99m}$Tc is such an important isotope, the fission yield of mass 99 that results in $^{99m}$Tc is measured quite well (and easily through the characteristic gamma emitted through $^{99m}$Tc decay used in the medical diagnostics). The result is that about 6.1% of the low mass fission products are known to be $^{99}$Mo. It even turns out that the yield of mass 98 (and 97, another possible Mo isotope) are somewhat lower, roughly 5.7 and 5.8% respectively.

Further, as we well know, fission of $^{235}$U is easy. Really, really, really easy. In fact, the cross section for fission with thermal neutrons is about 30,000 barns which is larger than the $^{98}$Mo(n,$\gamma$)$^{99}$Mo reaction by a factor of 3000 or more. Now, of course, the problem is separating out the ${99}$Mo (and other Mo isotopes) from the debris, but that can be done chemically. You are left with Mo with a much higher proportion of $^{99}$Mo than you could possibly have obtained by simply irradiating pure $^{98}$Mo, much less natural Mo.

So, the $^{235}$U path has large advantages in both the cross-section (3000x) and the higher proportions of $^{99}$Mo vs other Mo isotopes (greater than 1:1 for $^{99}$Mo vs $^{98}$Mo). On a per-incident-thermal-neutron basis, you get roughly 180 time the yield of $^{99}$Mo through fission. The downside, of course, is the use of highly enriched $^{235}$U to get the easiest outcome, although some paths use low enriched uranium - just means more stuff to sift through to get the $^{99}$Mo in the end.